# JavaScript onload function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me explain what I would like to do. I have developed a web app and before my animation runs I would like to make sure that the images used in the animation have been loaded into the browser. As such here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
                                text: 'Downloading Web App',
                                textVisible: true,
                                theme: 'a',
                                html: ""});

    document.getElementById('Logo').onload = function()
    {

        if(KeepCount == 0)
        {
            KeepCount++;
        }
        else if(KeepCount == 1)
        {
            KeepCount = 0;
            $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );
            StartSplash();
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('Hand').onload = function(){

        if(KeepCount == 0)
        {
            KeepCount++;
        }
        else if(KeepCount == 1)
        {
            KeepCount = 0;
            $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );
            StartSplash();
        }
    };
});
```

KeepCount is declared globally. I've checked this in chromes developer tools and somehow the onload functions are never fired for some reason. Here is the HTML:

```
 <img id='Logo' class="logo objecttransition"  src="css/images/Logo.gif">
    <img  id='Hand'  class="hand objecttransition"  src="css/images/hand.gif">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: inside of jquery's `$.ready` function, it is very likely that the images have already loaded by the time you assign the onload event. onload won't fire if the images have already been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to agree with Jonathan. The `jQuery` docs for the `.ready` handlers located [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), state the following.

> ...While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>    page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>    such as images have been completely received...
>
> The .ready() method is
>    generally incompatible with the  attribute. If load
>    must be used, either do not use .ready() or use jQuery's .load()
>    method to attach load event handlers to the window or to more specific
>    items, like images.

If you wanted to make sure images were loaded first, then you may want to use

```
$(window).load(function()
{
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare this in .ready scope, i guess that kind of late.

Maybe load your images by javascript, then you can be sure they are ready !

```
function startLoadImages(){
 var image = new Image();
 image.load = function(){
  // i am done, inject me !!
 }
 image.src = "css/images/Logo.gif"
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  startLoadImages();
});
```