# onload function being skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my main function which calls my loadtexture function that loads two images and returns a base64 encode of the combined image but it keeps skipping my onload functions when it's trying to load the images.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {   
    var modelPath = "models/testhiddenUV.obj";    
    var texture = loadTexture();
    loadModel(texture, modelPath, "designCanvas");
}); 

function loadTexture() {
var frontImage = new Image();
var backImage = new Image();
var canvas = document.getElementById("designCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";        
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1024,1024);
//skips whole onload functions to the end
frontImage.onload = function() {
    frontImage.src = "models/wine.jpg";
    ctx.drawImage(frontImage,0,0);
    backImage.onload = function() {
        backImage.onload = "models.petro21.jpg";
        ctx.drawImage(backimage, 804, 0);
        return canvas.toDataUrl("image/png");     
    }
}
```

To me the code looks right and should execute, am I missing something with the onload function? Why does it skip those lines of code?

Comment: I think you need to set the image `src` outside the onload. It is when the specified image url has downloaded that `load` is triggered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript onload function not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360910/javascript-onload-function-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

```
.onload
```

is an asynchronous call-back. And you have to call it in order for it to run.

So basically:

```
frontImage.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(frontImage,0,0);
}  
frontImage.src = URL.createObjectURL("models/wine.jpg");

backImage.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(backimage, 804, 0);     
}
backImage.src = URL.createObjectURL("whateverURIyouhave");
```

Comment: I had tried doing onload separately like your example but it still did not enter the function when I put in breakpoints at those two places. I used my normal src as I did not know how to use createObjectURL and it was throwing and error at that and at my canvas.toDataURL.